# Conditional Expectation - using Wald's Equation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

> Let  $N\sim\!\mathcal{P}(\lambda)$ and $(X_i)_{i\!\geq{1}}$ iid, $X_i\sim\!Be(p)$. If $N$ and $(X_i)_{i\!\geq{1}}$ are independent for all $i$, calculate $P(\mathbb{E}(X_1+\ldots+X_N|N)=0)$.

So using Wald's equation and the fact that $(X_i)_{i\!\geq{1}}$ are iid, I know that $\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i|N)=N\mathbb{E}(X_1)=Np$

But, how do I calculate $P(\mathbb{E}(X_1+\ldots+X_N|N)=0)$?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: $P=P(N=0)=e^{-\lambda}$

Comment: Sure you were not asked to compute $P(X_1+\ldots+X_N=0\mid N)$ instead?

Comment: Yes,I`m sure.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As you found, $\mathsf E\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^N X_j\;\middle\vert\; N\right)= Np$

You know that $N\sim\mathcal P(\lambda)$ so you can find $\mathsf P(Np{=}0)$ from

$$\mathsf P(N{=}k) \;=\; \dfrac{\lambda^k\, {\sf e}^{-\lambda}}{k!}$$

Comment: Thanks man!
So, $P(Np=0)=P(N=0)$
And I really can I say that? I thought it would be wrong

Comment: @Starmathjd Yes, there's no problem say that when $Np=0$ then either $N=0$ or $p=0$. So unless the constant, $p$, is zero, therefore...